# ClojureScript - construct url conditionally in go block

Tags: url, asynchronous, clojure, clojurescript

I am using [cemerick/url](https://github.com/cemerick/url) to construct my URL for an ajax request.
However, some of the parameters of the query are coming from an asynchronous native callback. So I put everything in a `go` block, like the following :

```
(defn myFn [options]
  (go (let [options (cond-> options
                      ;; the asynchronous call
                      (= (:loc options) "getgeo") (assoc :loc (aget (<! (!geolocation)) "coords")))

            constructing the url
            url (-> "http://example.com"

                    (assoc-in [:query :param]  "a param")

                    ;; How do I not associate those if they don't exist ?
                    ;; I tried something along the lines of this, but it obviously doesn't work.
                    ;; (cond->  (and
                    ;;           (-> options :loc :latitude not-nil?)
                    ;;           (-> options :loc :latitude not-nil?))
                    ;;   (do
                    ;;     ))
                    ;; these will fail if there is no "latitude" or "longitude" in options
                    (assoc-in  [:query :lat] (aget (:loc options) "latitude"))
                    (assoc-in  [:query :lng] (aget (:loc options) "longitude"))

                    ;; url function from https://github.com/cemerick/url
                    (url "/subscribe")
                    str)])))
```

I would like to be able to be able to pass either `{:loc "local}` or `{:loc {:latitude 12 :longitude 34}}` or `{}` as a parameter to my function.
I feel that I am not using the right structure already.

How I should construct this url ?

Comment: It's not clear what your question has to do with `core.async`.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm kind of getting a sense of what you're asking, and it's probably an interesting question, but you should really clean up the title and question. Your example code is very messy and unclear. As for your comment at the end: a map seems a suitable data structure; what are your concerns?

Comment: @NathanDavis Well it forces me to have it inside a `go` block, which (I think) prevents me from using anonymous functions for instance.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis Agreed it looks messy (hence my question). The code above will not work if an empty map is passed as parameters (it should just ignore then the two last `assoc-in` calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you require code, which looks like that:

```
;; helper function
(defn add-loc-to-url-as [url loc k as-k]
  (if-let [v (k loc)]
    (assoc-in url [:query as-k] v)
    url))

;; define function, that process options and extends URL
(defn add-location [url options]
  (if-let [location (:loc options)]
    (if (string? location)
      ;;; it expects string, for {:loc "San Francisco"}
      (assoc-in url [:query :location] location)
      ;;; or map, for {:loc {:latitude 12.123, :longitude 34.33}}
      (-> url
          (add-loc-to-url-as location :latitude :lat)
          (add-loc-to-url-as location :longitude :lng)))
    url))

;; now you can use it in your block
;; ...
the-url (-> (url "http://example.com" "subscribe")
            (assoc-in [:query :param] "a param")
            (add-location options))
```